# How can i convert this Prometheus query to sum data for 24 hr and show this data day wise

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, promql

I have a tunatuya device for monitoring energy, i have managed to convert this data to Prometheus and getting consisting data every 30 sec for how much Power (W) a device is using at that time instant.

What i am trying to do is creating a grafana dashboard to view daily used (KWh)

so far i have converted the Power (W) to KWh and have data for every hour of the day now i need to sum it for 24h and show in panel.

```
avg_over_time(tuya_power{device="10Amp Smart Plug"}[1h])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iow8i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zATAt.png)

i can change timeshift to 24h but then i get a single bar which have only the average w data

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned changing time shift. Did you mean to change a time range in the query?